# iOS UIButton with UITextAlignmentLeft still centering text?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

**Problem:**
 
After setting a button's `titleEdgeInset` and `UITextAlignmentLeft` the button's title is still centered, not left-aligned.

**Details:**
 
I have a button 200px wide using a custom background with an image on the left. Since I don't want the button title to cover the image, I inset the title using `titleEdgeInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 45.0, 0.0, 0.0);`. This should make title label's x position start at 45px and end at 200px. I also want the button's title to be left-aligned to the image, so I also set `textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft`. However, the title text is still centered between 45px and 200px, not left aligned.

Why?

Here's the relevant code:

```
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 45.0, 0.0, 0.0);
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
[button setTitle:@"X"];
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

My test code:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 72);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rob.png"];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
[button setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0);
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Note that I set `button.contentHorizontalAlignment`, not `button.titleLabel.textAlignment`.  My result:

[image: Screen shot of label]

Answer (score 22):

set  contentHorizontalAlignment property for button, it will work.

```
YourButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```

**Swift 4.0**

```
YourButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.center
```

Answer (score 4):

Put a background color on the titleLabel.  I'm betting it's being sized to fit, so the text alignment won't matter.  It's only as long as it needs to be.  What you need to fix is the position of the label itself.  You might have to extend the UIButton and override layoutSubviews to get it right.  I've never seen a button with anything but a centered label.

Answer (score 2):

Set contentHorizontalAlignment property for a button:

```
yourButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

Set contentHorizontalAlignment property do the work. Thanks

```
yourButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = .left
```

Answer (score 0):

Just override the button's setter and try to set the contentHorizontalAlignment property in the setter:

```
-(UIButton *)yourButton {
      [_yourButton setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];

    return _yourButton;
}
```